# Unable to create a signed url using AWS and with IRSA enabled on kubernetes pods

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm looking to create a signed url so i can create an MQTT client.
For this, I would need a secret access key, access key id and session Token. As my pods use IRSA, I'm ideally looking to do this using temporary credentials that i retrieve using the aws sdk.

I've tried many things, this being the latest

```
import v4 from 'aws-signature-v4';


const role = await sts
    .assumeRole({
        RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::my-acc:role/my-role',
        RoleSessionName: 'some-random-session-name',
        DurationSeconds: 900,
    })
    .promise();        

const url = v4.createPresignedURL(
'GET',
awsConfig.iotDataEndpoint.toLowerCase(),
'/mqtt',
'iotdevicegateway',
'',
{
    key: role.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
    secret: role.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
    sessionToken: role.Credentials.SessionToken,
    protocol: 'wss',
    expires: 900,
    region: awsConfig.region,
})
```

which throws

```
User: arn:aws:sts::my-acc:assumed-role/my-role/token-file-web-identity is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::my-acc:role/my-role
```

I made sure that `arn:aws:sts::my-acc:assumed-role/my-role` has the permission to perform `sts:AssumeRole` and that there is a trust relation ship with the resource.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have included the client code, but not the Policy JSON for the `my-role`, so no one can _guess_ what is wrong with your setup

Comment: Sorry for that, Added an answer. In the end it was a AssumeRole policy issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the role that you're using for the IRSA also needs to have the permission to assume itsself.

adding the `sts:AssumeRole` permission to `arn:aws:iam::my-acc:role/my-role` for `arn:aws:iam::my-acc:role/my-role` fixed it